# Filter BigQuery Results in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I'm trying to filter rows in a BigQuery response based on a condition in Google Apps Script. I tried:

```
var rowsCountry = rows.filter(function(r) {
    return r.f.country_code = goodCountry;
    });
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Please find the documentation with the response structure [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query). I want to keep only the rows with goodCountry variable in the country_code field. Any help?

Comment: hmmm... your "r" object is the BigQuery response? (I don't really know Appsscript, but I'll try to help you from the BQ side) Mind posting the POST request your code actually makes? Because if you need filtering, I would filter when you query, not from the response.